# Descriptive Set Theory - definable sets can be partitioned into more pieces than elements of original set

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I just read that "In Descriptive Set Theory .... definable sets can .... counter intuitively .... be partitioned into more pieces than there are elements in the original set".

Would anyone have a reference which discusses / proves it ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: https://www.cmu.edu/math/people/faculty/conley.html

Comment: I work in descriptive set theory, which is the study of how the ability to define a set (say of real numbers) confers useful information about its mathematical properties.  Restricting your attention to definable sets rather than arbitrary sets can have counterintuitive consequences: sets can be partitioned into more pieces than there are elements in the original set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an incomplete quote. The phenomenon being described is less about definable *sets* than definable *maps*.

For example, consider the Vitali relation on the reals: $$a\sim b\quad\iff\quad a-b\in\mathbb{Q}.$$ The resulting quotient set $\mathbb{R}_\sim:=\mathbb{R}/\sim$ (renamed for kerning purposes) is nicely definable. Moreover, with some care you can cook up a nicely-definable injection $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_\sim$. However, in a precise sense there **is no** nicely-definable injection $\mathbb{R}_\sim\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (e.g. take "nicely-definable" to be "Borel"). So **once we agree to compare sets only using "nicely definable" maps**, we have a set which is smaller than one of its quotient sets.

Note that $\mathbb{R}_\sim$ and $\mathbb{R}$ "classically" have the same cardinality (assuming Choice of course - and in a sense, the definable-cardinality idea pointed out here is a "Choice-ification" of some combinatorics that can happen more literally in $\mathsf{ZF}$).

Comment: Since you seem to dislike the kerning, you might like to know that if you enclose a binary operator in curly braces, it won't be treated like a binary operator.  So, for example, `$\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$` typesets as $\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$.  Without the curly braces, you get $\mathbb{R}/\sim$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sweet, I didn't know that! (What I specifically dislike kerning-wise is how "$\mathbb{R}/\sim\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$" turns out. But "$\mathbb{R}/{\sim}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$" is much better.) I'll leave this answer as-is out of general inertia, but I'll follow your suggestion in the future.